# perl: execute a command via open and see if the command has finished

Tags: perl

```
sub do_something {
    while(1) {
        #see if $brcmd has finished here
        # if ($BR finished) ?
        sleep 1;


    }
}

open $BR, q{-|}, $brcmd
    or die 'Cannot open BR';

do_something();

my $err = !(close $BR)
```

in the above code, i am open `$brcmd` which does something long
inside `do_something()`, I want to be able to check if `$brcmd` has finished

any suggestions?

Comment: `waitpid` is your friend.

Comment: @Sobrique waitpid inside while(1) to see if $brcmd has finished?

Comment: @does it require pid of $brcmd? how would you get that?

Comment: `open` returns the `pid` when you open like this.

Comment: ohhhhhhh i didnt know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it's just something that does for a long time (i used to read stuff from it but no longer need to). I just want to be able to know if it is finished.
>
> i need to do completely something else while that is running but when that's finished i need to exit out. so i need to able to poll if it's done without capturing any out from it.

If those are your requirements, you should save the pid of the child (the return value of [`open`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#open-FILEHANDLE-EXPR)), and then, when the parent is done, [waitpid](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#waitpid-PID-FLAGS) on the child.

[perldoc -f open](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#open-FILEHANDLE-EXPR) actually has an example of this:

```
my $child_pid = open(my $from_kid, "-|") // die "Can't fork: $!";

# ...

if ($child_pid) {
    # am the parent:
    # either write $to_kid or else read $from_kid
    ...
   waitpid $child_pid, 0;
} else {
    # am the child; use STDIN/STDOUT normally
    ...
    exit;
}
```

Of course, if you really do not need to read anything from the external command, you can [fork](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#fork) then execute the external command using [exec](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfork.pod#exec).

Comment: yes, nonblocking waitpid is what i was looking for. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any hint about what `$brcmd` might be, but since you have opened a pipe from it I suggest that you read from that pipe and wait for end of file

Something like this, perhaps?

```
open my $br_fh, '-|', $brcmd or die "Cannot open BR command: $!";

my @output = <$br_fh>;
```

Comment: yeah its just something that does for a long time (i used to read stuff from it but no longer need to). I just want to be able to know if it is finished.

Comment: i need to do completely something else while that is running but when that's finished i need to exit out. so i need to able to poll if it's done without capturing any out from it